# Console connection to a 3COM Superstack 4 5000G-EI doesn't work

Tags: networking, hp

Console connection to a 3COM Superstack 4 5000G-EI doesn't work.

I have plugged the switch into a USB RS-232 to Ethernet console cable using the console port on the switch. using PuTTy following what it specifies in the manual. Does anyone have experience with these switches? I run windows 10 on a surface pro.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details such as what OS you are on. Seems to be Windows? But what version. Also, what is the exact make and model of the machine you are using in your attempts to do this?

Comment: Have you looked up the system documentation?

Comment: yeah I have, followed the instructions and didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just started working after messing around with the Prolific Drivers for my RJ-45 to RS-232 to USB console cable. Turns out you needed to install them a specific way by installing multiple drivers and then going into Device Manager and clicking remove drivers. So random :).

If anyone needed help with this, please feel free to email me on stavropurdie9@gmail.com because I know how hard it is to get legacy hardware working when there is piss all documentation.